# pdfminer.six installation: works okay in cmd prompt, but returns syntax error in the shell

Tags: python, module, installation, pip, pdfminer

I used pip install pdfminer.six in the command prompt, and the installation was successful.

**When I run pdf2txt.py C:\Python27\pdfminer\samples\simple1.pdf in the command prompt, the command was successful and returned this:**

```
c:\Python27>pdf2txt.py C:\Python27\pdfminer\samples\simple1.pdf
INFO:pdfminer.pdfdocument:trailer: {'Root': <PDFObjRef:1>, 'Size': 8}
INFO:root:Pages: Kids=[<PDFObjRef:4>]
INFO:root:Page: {'Parent': <PDFObjRef:3>, 'Type': /'Page', 'Contents': <PDFObjRef:5>, 'Resources': {'Font': {'F1': <PDFObjRef:7>}, 'ProcSet': <PDFObjRef:6>}, 'MediaBox': [0, 0, 612, 792]}
INFO:root:Processing page: <PDFPage: Resources={'Font': {'F1': <PDFObjRef:7>}, 'ProcSet': <PDFObjRef:6>}, MediaBox=[0, 0, 612, 792]>
INFO:root:render_contents: resources={'Font': {'F1': <PDFObjRef:7>}, 'ProcSet': <PDFObjRef:6>}, streams=[<PDFStream(5): raw=284, {'Length': 86}>], ctm=(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0)
INFO:root:get_font: create: objid=7, spec={'BaseFont': /'Helvetica', 'Subtype': /'Type1', 'Type': /'Font', 'Name': /'F1', 'Encoding': /'MacRomanEncoding'}
Hello

World

Hello

World

H e l l o

W o r l d

H e l l o

W o r l d


c:\Python27>
```

**However, when I run the same thing in the python shell under windows, it returns an error:**

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**and when I type in pdf2txt.py in the shell, it returns an error too:**

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
        pdf2txt.py
    NameError: name 'pdf2txt' is not defined
```

> > > 

Can any one help me with this? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run python programs from Python shell — the shell is for Python code, not OS commands.

If you really want to run the program from Python shell instead of OS shell — use modules `os` or `subprocess`. Example:

```
import os
os.system('pdf2txt.py C:\\Python27\\pdfminer\\samples\\simple1.pdf')
```